# A simple code to detect any beacon in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ibeacon

I am new to swift programing , I am trying to develop app detecting beacons but still I can not detect any beacon.

```
let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID(UUIDString: "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111")!,major: 1, minor: 1,  identifier: "MyBeacon")
locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
```

Comment: Which beacon device is it?
iBeacon or Estimote?

Comment: iBeacon @Sharpkits

Comment: Can you show more of your code?  Specifically parts that set up  `locationManager.notifier=...` and the definition of the `didRangeBeacons` callback method.  You will need to have these if you do not already.

Comment: If you don't know the UUID, you can't. That's an iOS limitation. Also you can monitor a limited number of regions (don't remember if it was up to 8, 10 or 20) at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> SWIFT 3:

First of all you should add the **CoreLocation.Framework**

- In the .Plist file add the key/string `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`with appropriate string
- In your Object add the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`
- Add the  `CLLocationManagerDelegate` delegate methods in this example i will just add the didRangeBeacons method

> ```
> func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons
> beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
>            print(beacons)   }
> ```

- Create and initialise the locationManager

  `var locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()`
- Create the `CLBeaconRegion`

  ```
  let beaconRegion : CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(
      proximityUUID: NSUUID.init(uuidString:"****-****-****-****-******") as! UUID,
      identifier: "my beacon")
  ```
- Add the delegate to your Object `locationManager.delegate = self`
- Request the Location authorization from the user with

> locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

Now let's start the Range

```
  locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
```

This will automatically call the delegate method

```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
        print(beacons)

    }
```

Note : if you want to monitor beacon's entry/ exit state you need to add

```
locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
```

Finally : Make sure that your beacon is turned ON and you are testing the iBeacon Frame  Enjoy :D

Answer (score 6):

Beacons can be Detected in both Foreground as well as when in Background

**Step :- 1 Changes in info.plist**

In info.plist you need to change the “usage description” .
For that add the `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` with String type with your Message in it.

**Step :- 2 For Background Mode**

Add the Following Piece of Code in App Delegate :

```
var window: UIWindow?
var locationManager:CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    // Request permission to send notifications
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options:[.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in }
    return true
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    rangeBeacons()

}

func rangeBeacons(){
    let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "3e1d7817-4eac-4b27-b809-deee2f246c46")
    //let uuid = UUID(uuidString: "8492E75F-4FD6-469D-B132-043FE94921D8")
    let major:CLBeaconMajorValue = 1
    let minor:CLBeaconMinorValue = 2
    let identifier = "myBeacon"
    let region = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid!, major: major, minor: minor, identifier: identifier)
    region.notifyOnEntry = true
    region.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true
    region.notifyOnExit = true
    locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: region)
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Hello!!!"
    content.body = "You Are Back in the Office"
    content.sound = .default()
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "SufalamTech", content: content, trigger: nil)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Alert!!!"
    content.body = "You are Out of the Office"
    content.sound = .default()
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "identifier", content: content, trigger: nil)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil)
}
```

> Also Don't Forget to add `CLLocationManagerDelegate` and import `CoreLocations` and `UserNotifications`

**Step :- 3 For ForeGround or Active Mode**

Add the Following Piece of Code in ViewController

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    guard let discoveredbeaconProximity = beacons.first?.proximity else {print("Beacons Cannot be located"); return }

    if ((discoveredbeaconProximity == .far) || (discoveredbeaconProximity == .near) || (discoveredbeaconProximity == .immediate)) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You are in the Beacon Region", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    if discoveredbeaconProximity == .unknown{
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "You are out of the Beacon Region!!!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
        self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

> Note :- You Need To change your Beacon `UUID and Major and Minor` Value
>   accordingly

Comment: sorry my comment may be old..but anyone who is around may try answering...the code above worked PERFECT for foreground, but in background when I exit the app, or close my screen, it doesnt seems to run even after I put break points

Answer (score 3):

Simple Example:

Add `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to your `*.plist` file.

In your ViewController create your locationManager and your beaconRegion.
Set the locationManager delegate, request the authorization from the user and then start monitoring/ranging.

```
let locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
let beaconRegion : CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(
  proximityUUID: NSUUID.init(uuidString:"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111") as! UUID,
  major: 1,
  minor: 1,
  identifier: "my beacon")

locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
```

Add the extensions for CLLocationManagerDelegate:

```
extension ViewController : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    print(beacons)
  }

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion) {
    let beaconRegion = region as! CLBeaconRegion
    print("Did enter region: " + (beaconRegion.major?.stringValue)!)
  }

  func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion) {
    let beaconRegion = region as! CLBeaconRegion
    print("Did exit region: " + (beaconRegion.major?.stringValue)!)
  }
}
```

Note: Activate bluetooth, check if location-services are activated on your device (simulator not supported), with this region you will only find the beacon with exact this UUID+major+minor.

Comment: Thanks for effort @Rags93 i did what you said but still can not detect the beacon ... am i missing something??

Comment: Is "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111" your beacon UUID?

Comment: Would ask the same question: Have you entered your correct beacon UUID, major & minor?

Also - just to be sure - do you get the location-permission alert when fresh installing the app?

Comment: My UUID & major and minor is correct and still can not detect , what is the identifier

Comment: what is the identifier ... i do not know about it.

Comment: The identifier is just an name you define. This won't change anything when detecting.

Do you get the location-permission alert when fresh installing the app?