# Some confusion with CLBeaconRegion and didEnter\didExit region callbacks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, beacon

I discover some issue:
When i register `CLBeaconRegion` with only `UUID` and `identifier`, functions:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didExitRegion region: CLRegion)
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion)
```

are called nice.

But when i register CLBeaconRegion with `UUID`, `major` and `identifier` or with `UUID`, `major`, `minor` and `identifier`, these function not called.

Why? i cannot find any documentation about this behaviour.

Comment: It may be some other issue because major and minor not cause the ranging your beacon. Go through this tutorials may be you missed some thing https://www.raywenderlich.com/152330/ibeacon-tutorial-ios-swift

Comment: Do the major and minor values you have specified match the values in your beacon?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, major and minor match.

Comment: @rohitSidpara in this example didEnter\didExit not called too..

Comment: You should double check your major and minor; you should definitely get region entry exits

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Problem was with more then 20 regions a receive from back-end. And my test region was deleted every time, because 20 regions maximum for monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

For Future References Follow this Simple Tutorial For Ranging Beacons in Foreground as Well As Background.

[Beacon Basic Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448986/8306054)

**Note :- Always keep in Mind That a Maximum of 20 Beacons Regions Can Be Monitored Together. If u want To monitor more Beacons then you have to apply some logic like, For E.g: you can keep UUID for all same and Change Major and Minor Respectively.**