# How can you detect ANY iBeacon in swift?

Tags: swift, ibeacon

Is there any way to detect any iBeacon?

Some wildcard/joker for the uuid

in viewidload I have this code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    locationManager = CLLocationManager.init()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    startScanningForBeaconRegion(beaconRegion: getBeaconRegion())
}

func getBeaconRegion() -> CLBeaconRegion {
   let beaconRegion : CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: NSUUID.init(uuidString:"11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111")! as UUID,
        identifier: "my beacon")
    return beaconRegion
}

func startScanningForBeaconRegion(beaconRegion: CLBeaconRegion) {
    print(beaconRegion)
    locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)
    locationManager.startRangingBeacons(in: beaconRegion)
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], in region: CLBeaconRegion) {
    print(beacons)
}
```

Put on the uuid with 11111 does crash my app. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello you can possibly refer this link, I have explained here in detail about how to detect beacons https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448986/8306054

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to know about scanning for beacons and their regions, is the beacons UUID. Without having the beacons UUID you cannot scan in advance. The part of the code you have provided seems ok for scanning for beacons, but as I said you must know the beacon UUID in advance.
I think this apple documentation about region defining and scanning could be useful to you. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html

Comment: thank you , I realized that I mentioned something wrong. I think that in this web explain better how use the ibeacons https://solidgeargroup.com/beacons-on-android 

UUID: identify a group.
Major: identify a beacons subgroup in a bigger group.
Minor: identify a specific beacon. - > THIS HELPS ME A LOT